# After handling Alert and waits,The page is not loading and cannot locate elements. (in Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng-annotation-test

**After handling Alert and waits(popup at runtime,**)The page is not loading which is why cannot locate elements. (in Selenium)getting  **no such element: Unable to locate element**:

''''public class ApplicantLoginPageTest extends TestBase{

```
  @Test
    public void init() throws Exception { 
      
     
    ApplicantLoginPage applicantLoginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, ApplicantLoginPage.class);
    
      applicantLoginPage.getApp(prop.getProperty("urlapp"));
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      
      applicantLoginPage.login(prop.getProperty("un"));
      Thread.sleep(3000);
            
      applicantLoginPage.instruct1();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      
      applicantLoginPage.TestClick();
      try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
         applicantLoginPage.TestCamera();
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        applicantLoginPage.PreviewRecord();
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        applicantLoginPage.instruct2();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}''''
```

Comment: What is error you are getting? can you share web page with URL ?

Comment: No Such Element Exception as the page couldn't load and cannot locate elements  https://candidate-interview.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

remove the following statement, and try again:

```java
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```